# Disable Scrapyd item storing in .jl feed

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

**Question**

I want to know how to disable Item storing in scrapyd.

**What I tried**

I deploy a spider to the Scrapy daemon [Scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The deployed spider stores the spidered data in a database. And it works fine.

However Scrapyd logs each scraped Scrapy item. You can see this when examining the scrapyd [web interface](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#web-interface).
This item data is stored in `..../items/<project name>/<spider name>/<job name>.jl`

I have no clue how to disable this. I run scrapyd in a Docker container and it uses way too much storage.

I have tried [suppress Scrapy Item printed in logs after pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390945/suppress-scrapy-item-printed-in-logs-after-pipeline), but this does nothing for scrapyd logging it seems. All spider logging settings seem to be ignored by scrapyd.

**Edit**
I found this entry in the documentation about [Item storing](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#items-dir). It seems if you omit the `items_dir` setting, item logging will not happen. It is said that this is disabled by default. I do not have a *scrapyd.conf* file, so item logging should be disabled. It is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing my answer I re-read your question and I see that what you want has nothing to do with logging but it's about not writing to the (default-ish) `.jl` feed (Maybe update the title to: "Disable scrapyd Item storing"). To override scrapyd's default, just set `FEED_URI` to an empty string like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=tutorial -d spider=example -d setting=FEED_URI=
```

For other people who are looking into logging... Let's see an example. We do the usual:

```
$ scrapy startproject tutorial
$ cd tutorial
$ scrapy genspider example example.com
```

then edit `tutorial/spiders/example.py` to contain the following:

```
import scrapy

class TutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    surname = scrapy.Field()

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"

    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in xrange(100):
            t = TutorialItem()
            t['name'] = "foo"
            t['surname'] = "bar %d" % i
            yield t
```

Notice the difference between running:

```
$ scrapy crawl example
# or
$ scrapy crawl example -L DEBUG
# or
$ scrapy crawl example -s LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

and

```
$ scrapy crawl example -s LOG_LEVEL=INFO
# or
$ scrapy crawl example -L INFO
```

By trying such combinations on your spider confirm that it doesn't print Item info for log-level beyond debug.

It's now time, after you deploy to scrapyd to do exactly the same:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d setting=LOG_LEVEL=INFO -d project=tutorial -d spider=example
```

Confirm that the logs don't contain items when you run:

[image]

Note that if your items are still printed in INFO level, it likely means that your code or some pipeline is printing it. You could rise log-level further and/or investigate and find the code that prints it and remove it.

Comment: I hoped your suggestion worked. However it doesn't. I tried LOG_LEVEL=WARN. It does not make any difference.  How is this setting another setting than the log level in the settings file?

Comment: Well done for using docker by the way. I don't know exactly how you use scraped data but in general you get lower overhead if you e.g. bulk upload your `Item`s after crawling completes instead of doing it while you crawl in some item pipeline. This is the concept behind those `.jl` files. That you will hook to the `spider_closed` signal and use a bulk tool to upload this `.jl` file. But there are also rare cases where this isn't recommended/possible such as if you want minimum latency.

Comment: In the pipeline I directly save to a MySQL database running in another Docker container. I overwrite the process_item method `def process_item(self, productitem, spider):`

Comment: Great answer!  Your answer explains how to both disable item storing and logging. Your solution works.