# How to sort the scrapy item info in customized order?

Tags: python, scrapy

The default order in scrapy is alphabet,i have read some post to use OrderedDict to output item in customized order.
I write a spider follow the webpage.
[How to get order of fields in Scrapy item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293916/how-to-get-order-of-fields-in-scrapy-item/41301998#41301998)

My items.py.

```
import scrapy
from collections import OrderedDict


class OrderedItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._values = OrderedDict()
        if args or kwargs:  
            for k, v in six.iteritems(dict(*args, **kwargs)):
                self[k] = v

class StockinfoItem(OrderedItem):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
```

The simple spider file.

```
import scrapy
from info.items import InfoItem

class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Info'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.money.163.com']
    start_urls = [ "http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html"]
    def parse(self, response):
        item = InfoItem()
        item["name"] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()
        item["phone"] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/table/tr[7]/td[4]/text()').extract()
        item["address"] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/table/tr[2]/td[4]/text()').extract()
        item.items()
        yield  item
```

The scrapy info when to run the spider.

```
2019-04-25 13:45:01 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html>
{'address': ['浙江省杭州市天目山路152号浙能大厦'],'name': ['浙能电力'],'phone': ['0571-87210223']}
```

Why i can't get such desired order as below?

```
{'name': ['浙能电力'],'phone': ['0571-87210223'],'address': ['浙江省杭州市天目山路152号浙能大厦']}
```

Thank for Gallaecio's advice, to add the following in settings.py.

```
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS=['name','phone','address']
```

Execute the spider and output to csv file.

```
scrapy crawl  info -o  info.csv
```

The field order is in my customized order.

```
cat info.csv
name,phone,address
浙能电力,0571-87210223,浙江省杭州市天目山路152号浙能大
```

Look at the scrapy's debug info :

```
2019-04-26 00:16:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html>
{'address': ['浙江省杭州市天目山路152号浙能大厦'],
 'name': ['浙能电力'],
 'phone': ['0571-87210223']}
```

How can i make the debug info in customized order?How to get the following debug output?

```
2019-04-26 00:16:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html>
{'name': ['浙能电力'],
 'phone': ['0571-87210223'],
 'address': ['浙江省杭州市天目山路152号浙能大厦'],}
```

Comment: You can customize the field order in an actual output file. See [FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in `__repr__` function of `Item`. Originally its code is:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return pformat(dict(self))
```

So even if you convert your item to `OrderedDict` and expect fields to be saved in the same order, this function applies `dict()` to it and breaks the order.

So, I propose you to overload it in the way you like, for example:

```
import json

class OrderedItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._values = OrderedDict()
        if args or kwargs:
            for k, v in six.iteritems(dict(*args, **kwargs)):
                self[k] = v

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(OrderedDict(self), ensure_ascii = False)  # it should return some string
```

And now you can get this output:

```
2019-04-30 18:56:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html>
{"name": ["\u6d59\u80fd\u7535\u529b"], "phone": ["0571-87210223"], "address": ["\u6d59\u6c5f\u7701\u676d\u5dde\u5e02\u5929\u76ee\u5c71\u8def152\u53f7\u6d59\u80fd\u5927\u53a6"]}
```

Comment: Add  `ensure_ascii = False  in json.dump ` to show characters in cjk apperance.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a custom string representation of your item

```
class InfoItem:
    def __repr__(self):
      return 'name: {}, phone: {}, address: {}'.format(self['name'], self.['phone'], self.['address'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your spider replace `item.items()` with `self.log(item.items())`, log msg should be list of tuples in order you assigned them in your spider.

Another way is to combine answer you mentioned in your post with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910531/10844134)

Answer (score 0):

The whole items.py which can output customized dubug info in cjk apperance is as below.

```
import scrapy
import json    
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._values = OrderedDict()
        if args or kwargs:
            for k, v in six.iteritems(dict(*args, **kwargs)):
                self[k] = v

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(OrderedDict(self),ensure_ascii = False)  
        #ensure_ascii = False ,it make characters show in cjk appearance.

class StockinfoItem(OrderedItem):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
```